# django create links from directory contents

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I am new to Django and haven't used Python for quite some time. I am trying to have Django pull files from a directory, create a list item and then create a hyper link to the location of that file. So far this is how I've defined it in my views:

```
    def docs(request):
        root="/Users/user"
        workingDir="files"
        Path=os.path.join(root, workingDir)
        os.chdir(Path)
        files=os.listdir(".")
        dirListUrls=[]
        for file in files:
            dirListUrls.append(os.path.join(root, workingDir, file)

        directoryList={'dirList': {'files': files, 'dirListUrls': dirListUrls}
        return render(request, 'mySite/documents', directoryList)
```

In my template is the following:

```
{% for item in dirList.files}
    <li><a href="#">{{ item }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to create a dictionary that could be accessed in following way:

```
{% for item in dirList %}
    <li><a href="{{ dirList.url }}">{{ dirList.file }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me it sounds like you're trying to serve either static or media files. Take a look at the documentation how to do these: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

```
def docs(request):
    ...
    context = {'dirList': zip(files, dirListUrls)}
    return render(request, 'mySite/documents', context)
```

and

```
{% for item in dirList}
    <li><a href="#{{ item.1 }}">{{ item.0 }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The zip function worked for what I needed, thank you.

Comment: @tonryray If my answer solved your problem, you can accept it as so: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers